# UPNP - How I can create multiple instances of service of same type in one device

Tags: service, device, upnp

UPNP declares that when I announce device services, only one announce must be sent per service type under device (or subdevice).

I have a question - how I can differ the services in the such situation? And, when I creating the device, what I must to do to differ the same services?

Is it only need to set different serviceId, serviceControlUrl, eventSubUrl for each service instance?

Comment: Do you want to host multiple instances of the same service on a single device?  Some background to your requirements would be good in this case - there may be easier ways to achieve your requirements.

Comment: First - I write my own UPNP device. Second - I write my own lib to operate with UPNP devices :) Currently there is no need to create multiple instances of service under one device, but I want to find the way how to operate in such situation

Comment: If I ever needed this, I'd be tempted to place each service instance into a separate device.  The UPnP forum device architecture doc does appear to allow multiple instances of the same service per device though, given that you set unique values for serviceId, serviceControlUrl and eventSubUrl as you suggest.